# How to accept user input as the length of a vector in C++

Tags: c++, vector

How do i use userinput to determine the length of a vector? When using std::cin the size of the vector is always set to one despite what number i input. Any help would be appreciated.

```
int main()
{
    std::cout << "How many students do you want to enter?\n";
    int numOfStudents{};
    std::cin >> numOfStudents;

    std::vector results{ std::size_t(numOfStudents) };

    for (int i{ 0 }; i <= numOfStudents; ++i)
    {
        std::cout << "Enter a name: \n";
        std::string name;
        std::cin >> results[i];
        
    }
```

Comment: This is the nice effect of uniform initialization, my recommendation - do not use it if you do not want long hours of debugging for stupid mistakes.

Comment: @Slava In this case, it's more CTAD that's at fault than uniform initialization. If the value_type was specified,  it works fine.

Comment: @cigien unfortunately using uniform initialization and make it a habit will lead to the issues like this. Right, in this particular case it should fail to compile as `std::string` cannot be initialized with `std::size_t`, but sooner or later OP will need to create a `std::vector<int>` or something else that accepts initializer list. Been there done that.

Comment: @Slava Fair enough, I've edited my answer to address both issues. Still, the dupe is not correct though.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

On this line:

```cpp
std::vector results{ std::size_t(numOfStudents) };
```

You have not specified the `value_type` of the `vector`, so the compiler is forced to do class-template-argument-deduction (CTAD) to figure out the type of `results`. It sees a single `size_t` variable in the brace-initializer, and decides that `results` is a `std::vector<size_t>` containing a single element whose value is `numOfStudents`, and hence it has a size of 1.

Since you don't have any values to use for CTAD, you need to do this instead:

```cpp
std::vector<std::string> results{ std::size_t(numOfStudents) };
```

Which calls the single-argument constructor of `vector` that constructs the `vector` with count elements.

Note that using braces can still lead to issues when the constructor argument is convertible to the `value_type`, so you could do this to avoid those issues:

```cpp
std::vector<std::string> results( std::size_t(numOfStudents) );
```

In this case, the cast to `size_t` is unnecessary.

```cpp
std::vector<std::string> results( numOfStudents );
```

Also, note that your loop goes out of bounds. The loop condition should be this instead:

```cpp
i < numOfStudents
```

Comment: Shouldn't `(std::size_t(numOfStudents)) ` be just `(numOfStudents)`?

Comment: @doug it works either way. Added that it's unnecessary.

Comment: Of course. Just not common to see it. Good answer, BTW.

Answer (score 1):

You can enter the vector then resize it to `numOfStudents` because initial size of vector is 0,
like this :-

```
std::vector<std::string> result;

result.resize(numOfStudents);
```